# How to change UILabel height according to content in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am facing a problem on dynamic Label height.My requirement is like below image:

[image]

I am taking a `UIScrollView` and on `UIScrollView` I am adding `UILabel` for showing content. My content is different type of text size. If I set 1 content its coming perfect but if I take content within a Array then its coming like below image:

[image]

There are 6 content with different size of text. I implement this type:

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 42, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 152)];
[scroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[scroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[scroll setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];

contentArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla",@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ",@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu",@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla",@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et ", nil];


float x_pos = 5;
float y_pos = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < contentArr.count; i ++)
{
    NSString *text1 = [contentArr objectAtIndex:i];
    CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(152.5, 2000);
    CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    NSLog(@"size1.height == %f",size1.height);

    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x_pos,y_pos,152.5,size1.height)];
    bgView.backgroundColor = APP_BGCOLOR;
    [scroll addSubview:bgView];

    [bgView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:(170.0 / 255.0) green:(170.0 / 255.0) blue:(170.0 / 255.0) alpha:0.5] CGColor]];
    [bgView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
    bgView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    UILabel *lblComment = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7,20,bgView.frame.size.width -14,bgView.frame.size.height - 20)] ;
    [lblComment setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    lblComment.numberOfLines = size1.height/15;
    [lblComment setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
    lblComment.text = text1;
    lblComment.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblComment.tag = 1;
    [lblComment setNeedsDisplay];
    [bgView addSubview:lblComment];

    x_pos = x_pos + 157.5;

    if (x_pos > 300)
    {
        x_pos = 5;
        y_pos = y_pos + size1.height + 10;
    }

    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, y_pos)];
}
```

If I take only 1 content and write code for dynamic text height before For loop then its coming like 2nd Image.

I am following this code:

```
NSString *text1 = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";

CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(152.5, 2000);
CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

How to solve this issue?

If any idea, Please suggest me...

Comment: Have you tried `[UILabel fitToSize]`?

Comment: Yes i set fitToSize, after that same result no changes. If i set only 1 data then its coming ok, otherwise if I take from array its not coming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways you could do that:

**#1 caculate textSize then set to label:**

```
- (CGSize)calculateSizeWithNSString:(NSString *)str {
  CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, FLT_MAX);
  UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
  NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
  paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

  NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary
      dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, paragraph,
                                   NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f) {
  CGRect rect = [str boundingRectWithSize:constraint1
                             options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin |
                                      NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                          attributes:attributesDictionary
                             context:nil];
    constraint1 = rect.size;
  } else {
        //sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: was deprecated from iOS7.0
        constraint1 = [str sizeWithFont:font
                      constrainedToSize:constraint1
                          lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
      }
      return constraint1;
    }
```

**#2 Set text to label then use sizeThatFit: method to calculate true size contraint:**

```
- (void)changeLabelSize:(UILabel *)label {
  CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
  CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, FLT_MAX);
  CGSize expectSize = [label sizeThatFits:constraint1];
  labelFrame.size = expectSize;
  label.frame = labelFrame;
}
```

I think `sizeThatFits:` is a better option than `[label sizeToFit]` in this case because you want to supply one of the dimensions (the column width) as an argument: (big thank [Jef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595279/jef) for correct me)

See [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit)

**#EDIT:** Use method 2:

```
//.....
 // remove this line you dont need it any more
 CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
//...
[lblComment setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
    lblComment.text = text1;
[self changeLabelSize:lblComment];
CGSize size1 = lblComment.frame.size; //for your calculate x_pos, y_pos code
[bgView addSubview:lblComment];
//....
```

## EDIT 2: x_pos, y_pos calculate

I have an idea for calculate x_pos, y_pos

```
    float col1_y_pos = 5;
    float col2_y_pos = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < contentArr.count; i ++)
    {
        BOOL isColumn1 = (i%2 == 0)
        float x_pos = isColumn1 ? 5 : column2_x_pos_value;
        float y_pos = isColumn1 ? col1_y_pos: col2_y_pos;
        //your code set label frame with x_pos, y_pos
        //....
        CGSize size1 = lblComment.frame.size; 
        [bgView addSubview:lblComment];
        if (isColumn1) { 
           col1_y_pos += size1.height + marginTop;
        } else {
          col2_y_pos += size1.height + marginTop;
        }
   //....
```

Comment: this is a good answer, but there is nothing wrong with using sizeToFit.  The notes you quote advise against OVERRIDING this method, not against using it....  Good job

Comment: @Jef thank for your comment, I know my quote not right at all, but I don't know say how. I'm not good at English :( do you have some idea ?

Comment: perhaps you should say sizeThatFits:  is a better option in this case because you want to supply one of the dimensions (the column width) as an argument...

Comment: Where have to call this 2 method. Please explain. :)

Comment: @SRNayak you can use method #2 after you set text for label :)

Comment: directly i am write the code ya we have to call this method?

Comment: First when I allocate Label , that time I have to set the frame size ya only UILabel *lblComment = [[UILabel alloc] init] ; ?

Comment: Method 2 only change your label height to correct value

Comment: Yes Dude, its coming properly, but not for 2 column. If i set it for 1 column its coming perfect, How to make it for 2 column . please help

Comment: do the same with column 2. I think problem is code calculate x_pos, y_pos,  you should change some thing

Comment: @Huy Nghia : Please check my code : https://www.dropbox.com/s/zz5fzftyrshgs42/Dynamic_LabelHeight.zip?dl=0

Comment: @SRNayak Sorry I can't check now, But I will check your code until I free (about 2h later) :( I'm so sorry

Comment: @SRNayak I has an idea for calculate your label y_pos with 2 column, see my edit

Comment: But I want to add a View according to text size and on this view I want to add this label? How can i add?

Comment: I can't get you, can you explain more ?

Comment: I need a UIView beside of UiLabel. Becoz I need 2 Heading before that text. So i want to take a UIView and on that view I am adding this Lebel and 2 Header Lebel. How can i Set the view according to text font Size.

Comment: @SRNayak:  I see it. I think you should creat a custom object `CommentView:UIView`,which has content, title , card and most important It caculate  height by itseft with labels, margin. Then you just only add for your ScrollView

Answer (score 1):

You are having two columns for your texts. Labels in each row are different heights and you are having only 1 float `y_pos` to set label position. If you can see every `label` in first column is placed equal to column 2 label only because you are maintain `y_pos` according to 2nd column. You need to maintain `y_posLeft` `y_posRight`.

```
 float x_pos = 5;
    float y_posLeft = 5;
    float y_posRight = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < contentArr.count; i ++)
    {
        NSString *text1 = [contentArr objectAtIndex:i];

//        UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x_pos,y_pos,152.5,9999)];
//        bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
//        [scroll addSubview:bgView];

        UILabel *lblComment = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x_pos, (i%2 == 1)?y_posRight:y_posLeft, 152.5, 1999)] ;
        [lblComment setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        lblComment.numberOfLines = 0;
        [lblComment setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
        lblComment.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblComment.text = text1;
        [self changeLabelSize:lblComment];
        CGSize size1 = lblComment.frame.size;
        [scroll addSubview:lblComment];

        [lblComment.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
        [lblComment.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        lblComment.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
        lblComment.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        if (x_pos == 5)
        {
            y_posLeft = y_posLeft + size1.height + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            y_posRight = y_posRight + size1.height + 10;
        }

        x_pos = x_pos + 157.5;

        if (x_pos > 300)
        {
            x_pos = 5;
        }


        [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, MAX(y_posLeft, y_posRight))];
    }
```

Comment: I did not check it on xcode you may have to make little fixes to make it work. Or you can send me your code i'll send you fixed :)

Comment: How can i send? mail id please

Comment: But you need to remember both columns Y position to make it work as both column have different heights.

Comment: post it to dropbox and share public link here in comments.

Comment: Please check this link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/zz5fzftyrshgs42/Dynamic_LabelHeight.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks Dude. Thank u so muchhhhhhhhhh. U help me out from last 2 days struggling...Thanks a lots :)